# Can I use s SAS-expander without a dedicated hardware RAID Card?

Tags: software-raid, zfs, jbod

I'm trying to expand my ZFS raid setup and I have used up all the available Sata-ports on my motherboard. I have read about SAS Expanders online and I think i have understood what they do. But one detail seems to be skipped everywhere I looked. I know that SAS Expanders are supposed to be connected (through sff-8087) to a dedicated RAID card. The controller I have found has a 8x pcie slot. Why does a SAS expander that is supposed to transfer the data through the RAID Controller need such a big bus? wouldn't a 1x pcie slot be enough for transfering configuration (or whatever) to the SAS-expander? Or does this imply that I can transfer the actual data though the PCIe bus and skipp the RAID card if I don't want hardware RAID and just want to attatch disks to be passed through to the os (as JBOD)?

SAS-Expander: "HP 24-Bay 6G SAS Expander Server Card - 8x SFF-8087, 1x SFF-8088, PCI-E - 487738-001 / 468406-B21"

Comment: pcie x1 isn't enough because you could connect a 100+ hard drives, and even with a small array of SSD total bandwidth can saturated.  2 SSD is 1gb/s read.  ALL data has to go through the pcie bus not just the configuration data.

Comment: It may be that long just to provide enough “grip”. The connected cables may exert quite some force on the PCIe connector, it’s like a lever.

Comment: @cybernard expanders typically use the PCIe connector purely for power and physical attachment; data is not usually (ever?) sent through through the PCIe slot.  The data is provided by the 4 lane 6gbs External SAS connector (24Gbs aggregate bandwidth).  The HBA connecting to it would typically be x4 or x8 PCIe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that SAS Expanders are supposed to be connected (through sff-8087) to a dedicated RAID card.

Expander must be connected to a RAID controller or a HBA (HBA can work in IT passthru or RAID mode, both will work).

> The controller i have found has a 8x pcie slot.

Long story short: Integrated Intel chipset on motherboard (e.g. 8 sata connectors) drops speed proportionally to number of drives connected to chipset. 8 drives have pathetic benchmark when tested simultaneously. That is NOT the case with HBA/RAID. 20 drives will still have e.g. 400MB read and write thruput. Now you understand why 8x.

> why does a SAS expander that is supposed to transfer the Data through the Raid Controller need such a big bus?

Expander chip consumes a lots of power, you can see it by temperature it generates, 12G expander heats to +90 celsius. Data does not travel thru the PCIe bus between Controller/HBA and Expander, it uses one/two uplink cables usually port 0 and 1 on expander. (If wrong ports are used, you will lose hierarchy, but will still work, read the manual of expnder for correct ports).

> or does this imply that i can transfer the actual Data though the PCIe bus and skipp the RAID card if i dont want hardware RAID and just want to attatch disks to be passed through to the os (as JBOD)?

Expander won't do a thing if it's not connected to either HBA or RAID. Try to see Expander as some kind of multiplexer not as a controller itself.

> SAS-Expander: "HP 24-Bay 6G SAS Expander Server Card - 8x SFF-8087, 1x SFF-8088, PCI-E - 487738-001 / 468406-B21"

It's highly compatible expander and will work with just anything you connect to it. Unlike its' sibling 12G expander which is damn picky (had a nightmare with 6 different models of IBM controllers/HBAs I had).

Have I answered all the questions you posted in such small article?

Answer (score 2):

SAS expander requires an HBA (Host Bus Adapter).

You can find SAS expanders that do not require a PCI-e interface, and those that do, simply use the PCI-e interface for power and a place to mount the hardware. all data communication is via the SAS cable from the HBA to the expander.